# What are the criteria for receiving tag-badges?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

There are two types of badges:

1. There is a set of pre-defined badges like “nice answer” or “yearling”. Each badge has its own rules, and there is a complete list of all such badges that are available. In the users profile they are shown with a white text on a black background.
2. Beside them there is a generic type of badges. You can get those badges for answering questions that are tagged with the same tag. If you answer at least 20 questions with the same tag and get for this questions at least 100 points, then you get a bronze badge for this tag. In the users profile this badges are displayed with a grey text on a light-grey background.

I am talking about this second type of tags. As just mentioned, you get a bronze badge for:

> Earn at least 100 total score for at least 20 non-community wiki answers in the <*tag-name*> tag.

Maybe I don't understand the english term “non-community wiki answers”. (English is a foreign language to me, I would prefer German descriptions in this German board.) I guess this just means a normal answer to a normal question, meaning that the question was asked not by me but by another person, and that question and answer was not posted in meta.

If this is true, I don't understand why I didn't get badges for tags that should meet those criterions.

This is a list of my top answered tags with scores above 100:

- “meaning” score=176, answers=44
- “translation” 174, 43
- “grammar” 166, 62
- “word-usage” 165, 39
- “differences” 150, 29
- **“austrian” 142, 22** <-- pay attention to this tag
- “word-choice” 126, 31
- “english-to-german” 119, 27
- “single-word-request” 100, 22

As far as I understand the criterion for tag-badges, I should have earned bronze-badges for all of this 9 tags.

But this is the list of bronze-tag-badges that I really received:

- “single-word-request”
- “word-choice”
- “differences”
- “word-usage”
- “english-to-german”
- “translation”
- “grammar”
- “meaning”

This makes 8 tags. I didn't get a tag for “austrian” (which is my favorite tag), but I earned a badge for “single-word-request” which has the same number of questions (22) but a lower score (100, compared to 142) than “austrian”.

What is the reason that I didn't get a bronze “austrian” tag badge?

Comment: “Non-community wiki answers” are answers that are not community wikis.

Comment: This is your only CW: http://german.stackexchange.com/a/4727

Comment: @chirlu: Das ist so erklärend wie: »"nicht-frotierende Rusch-Antworten" sind Antworten, die nicht frotierende Rusch sind«. Wenn man's vorher nicht verstanden hat, versteht man es danach nicht besser. Kannst du das stattdessen bitte auf Deutsch erklären?

Comment: Wegen der Betonung des Englischen klang es, als hättest du ein sprachliches Problem mit der Zusammensetzung, aber offenbar ist es eine inhaltliche Frage. Ausführliche Antwort hier: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you do have [22 posts](https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:1487+[austrian]) in [austrian](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/austrian) at the time of writing, [3 of them](https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1487+[austrian]+is%3Aquestion) are questions, and consequently, only [19 of them](https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1487+[austrian]+is%3Aanswer) are answers. So you need one additional answer.

Comment: Danke! (Die Mindestlänge für Kommentare nervt genauso wie die Maximallänge)

Comment: @Hubert Das liegt daran, dass _Danke!_ offiziell als "Rauschen" zählt. Das soll das jetzt nicht rechtfertigen, ich find das auch hacke.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu: Ja, ich kannte den Grund bereits. Trotzdem nervt es, dass man ab und zu nicht mal ein einfaches »Danke« ohne Beiwerk absondern darf. Aber ich versteh schon, warum das so ist. Ich wills auch nicht geändert haben. Ich musste nur irgendwas zusätzliches in die Tastatur klopfen, um das »danke« senden zu können.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to chirlu's answer, there is another requirement. On the [Tag Badges page](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze), on the right-hand column, it says:

> These badges are awarded for participating in non community-wiki questions with particular tags. **If enough votes are earned in a tag with 100+ total questions**, the badge will be automatically created and awarded.

The tag [austrian](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/austrian) has only 31 questions so far.